# ArrayList<String> doesn't set minimum capacity

Tags: java, string, for-loop, arraylist

```
private static ArrayList<String> places(ArrayList<Road> roads) {
    ArrayList<String> places = new ArrayList<String>(10); // tried setting minimum capacity
    places.ensureCapacity(10); // tried setting minimum capacity

    for (int i = 0; i < roads.size(); i++) {
        String from = roads.get(i).getFrom();
        String to = roads.get(i).getTo();

        for (int j = 0; j < places.size(); j++) { // this is where things go wrong, it doesn't iterate because the "j < places.size()" condition isn't met
            if ((places.get(i).equals(from))==false) {
                places.add(from);
            }
            if ((places.get(i).equals(to))==false) {
                places.add(to);
            }
        }
    }

    return places;
}
```

Don't know why but the places-ArrayList doesn't set an initial capacity which leads to not being able to iterate places when I have to later on (the for-loop which deals with the j-variable).

Comment: What error are you getting - how are you not able to iterate?  I suspect your actual problem is that `places.get(i)` is returning a `null` value, which you won't be able to call `equals()` on...  Oh, and most of the time using the 'not' operator - `!` - is used instead of `==false`

Comment: yep, `places.get(i)` is probably returning `null`, gonna see if I can fix that. I used the not-operator but changed to `==false`, I'll change back maybe, it may be good practice but I find it easier to wrap my brain around the design if I use `==false`.

Comment: Yes, except `==false` is evaluating to *true*, which is just confusing.  Also, consider switching to a `Set` implementation, as this seems to be what you are attempting to produce - that, or lookup the `contains()` method, which will deal with your null problem.

Comment: i just added an `if` before those for-loops stating that if the ArrayList is empty then something should be added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minimum capacity is different from size.  Setting the capacity is just a hint to the list that it should have at least this much storage to avoid unnecessary array copies, but does not affect the size so even though you have the capacity for n elements the `size()` can be less, and calling `get(n-1)` might result in an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

To create a list of size n that is filled with `null`, try

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) { myList.add(null); }
```

Answer (score 2):

The capacity attribute just gives the class a magnitude of how dimension its internal buffer. It does not add any values to the list (btw, which values would have been added?) so the list is still empty.

The only effect of capacity is to allow the class to avoid resizing its buffer (with the associated performance penalty) later in the execution. But it is not a hard limit. You can add or more elements at will as with any other List.

Answer (score 0):

Use `foreach` :

```
for(Road road : roads)
{
    String from = road.getFrom();
    String to = roads.getTo();
    for(Places place: places)
    {
        if(!place.equals(from)) places.add(from);
        if(!place.equals(to))   places.add(to);
    }
}
```

Comment: doh, I prefer to use fori than fore, but ok.. I'll give that a try, thanks.

Comment: While it is true that it is a way of iterate the content and that it may be "better", it has no relationship with the question. He asks why the list is empty even after he has set capacity.

Comment: Unfortunately, despite being a good idea, this won't actually help them with their issue.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList.ensureCapacity()` allocates enough memory to hold up to the given number of entries.  It doesn't actually put anything into the `ArrayList`.

`ArrayList.size()` counts the number of *actual* entries, not the current capacity.

Your loop looks at `places.size()` before you call `places.add()` to actually put anything into `places`.  When `places.size()` is called at the start of the loop it correctly returns 0 because at this point you haven't yet put anything into `places`.

One other point.  You have a method called `places` and within that method a local variable also called `places`.  That is a recipe for confusion.  You should use a different name for one of them.

Comment: changed the variable to `placesArr`